# Adding comma Separators for a value after a calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The calculation , i have setup 2 input fields where multiplication will take place. The text boxes will accept number input , while displaying comma separation to the value.Before the multiplication, i remove the commas and then pass the result to text box 3. How can i show the answer to the end user with comma separation for below instance ? Appreciate your great help.

```js
function calculate() {

  var E1 =   $("#E1").val().split(",").join(""); 
  var E2 =   $("#E2").val().split(",").join("");
  
  var result = E1*E2;
  $("#E3").val(result);
  
}


//For comma seperation
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="form-group">
    <label>Value 01</label>
    <input class="form-control number" type="tel" id="E1" required oninput="calculate()" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Value 02</label>
    <input class="form-control number" type="tel" id="E2" required oninput="calculate()" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Value 03 (Result)</label>
    <input class="form-control number" type="tel" id="E3"  />
</div>
```

Comment: `var E1 = +$("#E1").val().replace(/,/,'')` instead of split you can use join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just added `digits` function this function return make comma for every three digits. Hope this help you.

```js
function calculate() {

  var E1 = $("#E1").val().split(",").join("");
  var E2 = $("#E2").val().split(",").join("");

  var result = E1 * E2;
  $("#E3").val(result);
  $("#E3").digits();

}

$.fn.digits = function() {
  return this.each(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,"));
  })
}
//For comma seperation
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;

  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
    return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Value 01</label>
  <input class="form-control number" type="tel" id="E1" required oninput="calculate()" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Value 02</label>
  <input class="form-control number" type="tel" id="E2" required oninput="calculate()" />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Value 03 (Result)</label>
  <input class="form-control number" type="tel" id="E3" />
</div>
```

Comment: "I hope this helps you" is quite vague as an answer. Could you instead write what the problem is, how you fixed it, and why that works? That will surely help.

Comment: @trincot Thank you will make

Answer (score 1):

```
function calculate() {

  var E1 =   $("#E1").val().split(",").join(""); 
  var E2 =   $("#E2").val().split(",").join("");

  var result = E1*E2;
  $("#E3").val(result);
  formatNumber($("#E3"))

}

function formatNumber(input) {
  // format number
  input.val(function(index, value) {
    return value
    .replace(/\D/g, "")
    .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    ;
  });



//For comma seperation
$('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

  // skip for arrow keys
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;  

  formatNumber($(this))
});
```